# JavaScript regex to remove special characters and remove extra spaces while leaving commas

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to do two things to clean the string, the first is to remove any space and replace it with a comma separator, the second is to remove any non-alphanumeric characters (other than the comma); I have the first part functional, but now I can't figure out how to remove the special characters as well:

```
$("#fancydiv").keyup(function(e) {
    var str = this.value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1,$2');
    if (str!=this.value) this.value = str;
});
```

Comment: Not sure your first part is done right.  Try with `"a ,b, c,d  , e,f "` as input, the result will be `"a,b, c,d  , e,f"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'?no, special-characters!'.replace(/[^\w,]/g, '')
// => "no,specialcharacters"
```

`[^\w,]` will match match non-alphabet, non-digit, non-underscore character excluding a comma.

Comment: I ended up doing this, thank you! 

    var str = this.value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/[^\w,]/g, '');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = this.value.replace(/\s/g, ',').replace(/[^\w,]/g, '');
```

Comment: `a , b` would become `a,,,b`. I don't think this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Well, I think it's exactly what OP asked - "the first is remove any spaces and replace it with a comma separator"... whether an empty string is also a word was not defined in the question, as well as what to do with spaces surrounding commas. But yeah, probably he wanted only one comma between real words.